# How to access $sqlstate property of mysqli_sql_exception object?

Tags: php, exception, mysqli

The [mysqli_sql_exception class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php) defines a *protected* `$sqlstate` property that the manual defines as "The sql state with the error". However, there does not appear to be a corresponding getter method defined eg. `getSqlstate()` does not appear to exist!? Nothing is documented in the manual.

How are you expected to access this property?

Comment: I think you can just catch like: catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e), or try to extend this class by yours

Comment: @sergio Yes, I can catch the exception OK, but I can't access the $sqlstate property value. The `$e->getCode()` method returns the usual error code, not the SQLSTATE. I can extend the class, which would allow me to assign my own value to this property but that kinda defeats the object. (Besides, I wouldn't necessarily have access to the SQLSTATE via the mysqli object itself at this point in the code.)

Comment: It'd be ugly, but have you considered using Reflection?

Comment: @Charles: Using Reflection should be possible (but ugly as you say). However, I'm currently on a <5.3 machine so can't use the `setAccessible()` method on the protected property in order to get its value - so can't test this at the moment. However, another (ugly) way that works, is to cast the exception object to an array. I can then read the protected property. However, I do feel that there is something missing here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of possible (ugly) workarounds to read the protected `$sqlstate` property. The property appears to have a legitimate value, so there would seem to be something missing here!?

**Method 1** uses Reflection and is currently untested.

**Method 2** casts the object to an array and reads the protected property (prefixed with `*` and surrounded with null bytes!)

```
try {

    /* Code throws mysqli_sql_exception */

} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {

    // 1. Reflection
    //    Requires PHP 5.3+ for the setAccessible() method
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass($e);
    $property = $reflect->getProperty('sqlstate');
    $property->setAccessible(true); // PHP 5.3
    $sqlstate = $property->getValue($e);

    /* OR */

    // 2. Cast to an array and access "protected" property
    $eArr = (array)$e;
    $sqlstate = $eArr["\0*\0sqlstate"];

}
```